# Two IPs for the same network Adapter

Tags: windows, networking

I'm trying to set a static IP for my computer. When I change the IP from IPv4 properties, it doesn't take effect and here what I get with ipconfig cmd :

[image]

It seems that I have 2 different IPs for the same network adapter

[image]

And here is how I configured the adapter :

[image]

I can't use Internet anymore, however this used to work like sharm before. I'm sorry but I'm using french.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try `ipconfig -a` (or is it `-t` in French Windows?) to show all the entries, and check if there are two entries for the same network adapter. Also look at Device Manager and try removing and reinstalling the interface, especially if there are multiple entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the IP address 169.254.x.x is APIPA address, it will not be able to connect with the internet. First, you choose "Obtain Ip Address Automatically" instead of static IP. then click OK. and now run 'ipconfig'. Then you will get only 169.254.x.x address, again you should manually configure the static IP.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: goto Ipv4 properties->Advanced. Look if there is an entry 169.254.x.x, if so then delete it. If it doesnt work. then remove the 169.254.x.x address using CMD with Administrator privileges by using this "delete address [name=]InterfaceName [addr=] IPAddress"

Comment: Go to services and try disabling DHCP Client service to stop the preferred IPv4

Comment: After removing the 169... address _using CMD_ it worked